# How to get startOffset/endOffset of selected html text?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap selected text from a "contenteditable" div in a given tag. Below seems to be working ok but startOffset/endOffset doesn't include HTML text. My question is how do I get the Range object to count the html tags if they exist in the selection?

```
getSelectedText: function() {
  var range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    return [range.startOffset, range.endOffset];
  }
}


toggleTagOnRange: function(range, tag, closeTag) {
  var removeExp, val;
  if (closeTag == null) {
    closeTag = tag;
  }
  val = this.get("value");
  removeExp = RegExp("<" + tag + ">(.+)</" + closeTag + ">");
  if (removeExp.test(val)) {
    this.set("value", val.replace(removeExp, function(match, $1) {
      return $1;
    }));
  } else {
    if (range.length > 1) {
      val = val.splice(range[1], "</" + closeTag + ">").splice(range[0], "<" + tag + ">");
      this.set("value", val);
    }
  }
  return this.get("val");
}

// this is called from a bold button click handler.
this.toggleTagOnSelection(this.getSelectedText(), 'strong');
```

Interested in other solutions if you've got them.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, things can get pretty nasty when trying to write code for this type of thing yourself.  There are a lot of cases you need to cover, like when you're selecting text across multiple `<p>` tags for example.  You don't need to reinvent the wheel.  Look into a library like [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy) where they have already taken care of the nitty gritty details.  Specifically for your situation, if you can get by with using CSS styles instead of using tag elements like `<strong>`, look into the [CSS Class Applier Module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule), which allows you to do this simply by doing:

```
var cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("someClass", {normalize: true});
cssApplier.toggleSelection();
```

Where `.someClass` is a CSS class containing whatever styles you need to apply.

Comment: Ya, I'm starting to agree with you. I would mind using rangy it's just a little overkill for what I need. Is there something simpler out there that you know of? Preferably with an AMD implementation.

Comment: Hmm, looking quickly I don't see a whole lot else out there.  If you're using jQuery you could try the [wrapSelection](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/wrapSelection) plugin.

Comment: By the way, what exactly do you need?  Are you just looking to apply styles to a selection, or do you actually need to wrap a selection with certain HTML elements?